# Php Loop TD if rows didn't exist or match

Tags: php

i want to loop some DTR values and their absent in PHP

[image: 1]

As you can see the date should be 1,2,3,4,5 but since the only record they have is 3,4,5 there's some skipped rows, is it possible to loop empty TD and put missing date if there's no row exist? like i want to loop 1-31 then match the date then put the date where it belongs? idk dude

this is my code for my loop which basically just call the results of my query

```
              <?php foreach ($report_stmt as $row): ?>

                 <tr>
                  <td><?php 
                   $thisDate = $row['dtr_date'];
                   $day = strtotime($thisDate);
                   $newFormat = ltrim(date('d',$day),0);
                  echo $newFormat;     
                  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['dtr_in'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['dtr_out'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['dtr_in2'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['dtr_out2'] ?></td>
                </tr> 
             
                <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
```

this is my query

```
$report_list = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dtr INNER JOIN tbl_users_info ON tbl_dtr.dtr_by = tbl_users_info.user_info_email WHERE dtr_by = :user AND dtr_date LIKE '%$month_filter%' ";
```

Comment: Add your part of code

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question...

Comment: i added my code, thank you :)

Comment: could you please add in your question the output of `print_r($report_stmt);` executed right before your loop? e.g. If you do not have the IDs in your initial array, they will not be in the `foreach` loop either.. In the table you are providing I do not see 1 and 2 listed!

Comment: Does your `date` really start from `1`? How do you determine which `date` is the last one?

Comment: nah, that's the only record in the database, 1 and 2 are not listed because they didn't exist, is it possible to statically display the TR 1-31, then just put my row result where it match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to aggregate an array with the day of month as index. Then just loop through the day of months instead of loop through the query results.

Note: [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with 'j' is better than trimming leading zero with 'd'. You may read the [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for the details of all formatting character.

```php
<?php

// Aggregate an array of reports first
// Note: assume there is no 2 rows with the same 'dtr_date'
$reports = [];
foreach ($report_stmt as $row) {
  $row['date'] = date('j', strtotime($row['dtr_date']));
  $reports[$row['date']] = $row;
}

?>

<?php for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++): ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $reports[$i]['dtr_in'] ?? '' ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $reports[$i]['dtr_out'] ?? '' ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $reports[$i]['dtr_in2'] ?? '' ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $reports[$i]['dtr_out2'] ?? '' ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php endfor; ?>
```